# SavedIntanceState.getBoolean() is making my app crash (i think)

Tags: java, android, bundle, oncreate, onsaveinstancestate

**My Goal:**
So I need help putting a boolean primitives into a bundle and retrieving it from the bundle when there is a screen orientation change in Android. I am using that boolean value in a conditional statement that helps decide if 2 Button views (mTrueButton, mFalseButton) should be enabled or not. What i have so far is causing the app to shut down (aka crash) when there is a screen rotation. I think I am not retrieving or writing my boolean from my bundle or into my bundle correctly, and it is causing the app to crash.

**How The App Should Works:**
When a user touches the mTrueButton or mFalseButton button to answer a question, both buttons become disabled so the user is not allowed to answer again. I want those buttons to keep being disabled when the user answers and then rotates the screen.**

I know that when a user rotates their Android device, onDestroy() is called because runtime configuration changes take place, causing the app to be relaunched without having knowledge of it's previous state, (unless store my necessary data onto a bundle and pass it onto my onCreate method).

**These are SOME global variables in my activity class**

```
private int index = 0;
priavate Button mTrueButton,mFalseButton;
private static final String KEY_INDEX = "index";
private static final String BTTN_ENABLED = "bttnEnabled";
private boolean trueFalseButtonsEnabled = true;
```

**These are SOME statements in my onCreate() method of the same activity class**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate(Bundle) called");
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_quiz);

    if(savedInstanceState != null) {
        index = savedInstanceState.getInt(KEY_INDEX, 0);
        changeButtonEnableStatus(savedInstanceState.getBoolean(BTTN_ENABLED,true));
    }

    mTrueButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.true_button);
    mFalseButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.false_button);

    mTrueButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            checkAnswer(true);
            changeButtonEnableStatus(false);
        }
    });

    mFalseButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            checkAnswer(false);
            changeButtonEnableStatus(false);
        }
    });
}
```

**These are SOME methods in the same activity class but not in my onCreate()**

```
private void changeButtonEnableStatus(boolean bool){
    trueFalseButtonsEnabled = bool;
    mTrueButton.setEnabled(bool);
    mFalseButton.setEnabled(bool);
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    Log.d(TAG,"onSavedInstanceState() called");
    savedInstanceState.putInt(KEY_INDEX,index);
    savedInstanceState.putBoolean(BTTN_ENABLED, trueFalseButtonsEnabled);
}
```

**Note that:**
index = savedInstanceState.getInt(KEY_INDEX, 0);
works properly. It is setting global variable "index" to equal to the int primitive what was stored in into keywork "KEY_INDEX".

**However I don't think:**  changeButtonEnableStatus(savedInstanceState.getBoolean(BTTN_ENABLED,true));   is working properly. My app seems to crash when I include that statement and run the app, and then rotate the device.

Comment: Post the error shown in `logcat`

Comment: If you use Android Studio to develop that app, there is a Logcat bookmark on the bottom. You can open it and search for the error that crashes your app. If it isn't obvious what's wrong yet, you can share that error with us (edit your question to post the stack trace of the proper exception) and I think it will be easier for us to find out where the problem is.

Comment: @RafaelC thank you. You guided me to solving the issue. I forgot I could look at the logcat for the error description. It was a nullpointerexception. ChangeButtonEnableStatus() was trying to call mTrueButton.setEnabled(bool) and mFalseButton.setEnabled(bool) way before mFalseButton or mTrueButton even got a chance to have a reference ID assigned to them. During the first app launch, it was no problem because if(savedInstanceState != null) condition was false. After the onDestory() and the relaunch, the condition becomes true.

Comment: Makes sense :) Glad I could help. `logcat` is very useful for debugging :)